# Rails 4: create custom object in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, oembed

I'm trying to create a provider for oEmbed in Rails 4
The route, controller and action are created.

But I'm not able to create an object with the parameters that are needed for oembed (e.g. type, version, html, ...)

I was trying to do it this way:

```
class ServicesController < ApplicationController

    def oembed
        # get project ID
        url = params[:url].split("/")
        project_id = url[4]

        @project = Project.find(project_id)
        html = render_to_string :partial => "projects/oembed", :formats => [:html], :locals => { :project => @

        # here's the problem:
        oembed_response["type"] = "rich"
        oembed_response["version"] = "1.0"
        oembed_response["title"] = @project.name
        oembed_response["html"] = html

        respond_to do | format |
            if(@project)
                format.html { render :text => "Test" }
                format.json { render json: oembed_response, status: :ok }
                format.xml { render xml: oembed_response, status: :ok }
            else
                # error
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I always get the following error:

> NameError (undefined local variable or method `oembed_response' for #<ServicesController:0x007f9a8be579a0>):
>     app/controllers/services_controller.rb:11:in`oembed'

How can I achieve that I create a custom object with the needed attributes without a model and the (strong-) parameters like it's usually done?

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Chri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize `oembed_response` as empty hash first:

```
oembed_response = {}
```

Unrelated to this error, but you should change the way you get the object url from the id. Routes should parse the id automatically for you, eg. when you have this in the `routes.rb` file:

```
get "/projects/oembed/:id" => 'services#oembed'
```

Then you can access the id (given by `:id` in the routes path) directyl from the params hash:

```
project_id = params[:id]
```

Comment: In 3 minutes - I have to wait ;)

Comment: To the part under the empty hash: how could this work? because normally i have for example /projects/1 --> with this URL-scheme /:id works in the routes. but with oEmbed I get a request like "http://example.com/services/oembed?url=http://example.com/projects/4/&format=json", don't I?

Comment: But i have a way better solution now: `parsed_url = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path params[:url]`. Then it's possible to call the .find function with `parsed_url[:id]`. Just if somebody has the same problem ;)